# KDEConnect or similar under GNOME

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation, kde, kde-connect

I'm a KDE-User (Kubuntu, openSUSE, ArchLinux) since years. I pretty like GNOME and I'm thinking about switching over to GNOME - but every time I think about it I think: "Oh hey, wait a moment, you can't use KDEConnect anymore - Ok, I'll stay with KDE"

I really love the shared clipboard and the Android notifications in KDE-Desktop.
Is there any way to get this features under (Ubuntu) GNOME?
I heard of DeskCon and LinConnect, but both of them seem not to be an real replacement.

Any help?

Comment: I think installing `kdeconnect` will give you the feature.

Comment: @Zacharee1: Rly? I think it uses Klipper and other KDE-stuff, doesn't it?

Comment: If it does, those packages will install automatically. KDE is just another desktop environment for Ubuntu; all its individual packages are available to install on any flavor of Ubuntu.

Comment: As @TheWanderer suggests `kdeconnect` does work. At least in Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity Interface. I haven't tested Ubuntu 18.04 yet.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could just install `kdeconnect` on Ubuntu GNOME, it would probably also install lots of KDE dependencies, but if you're fine with that then just install it and you'll get the functionality you want. Installing it and its dependencies shouldn't cause any problems and they will be available to all flavours with access to the official repositories (`main`, `universe`, `restricted` and `multiverse`).

But you should be aware that as you are not on a system with KDE libraries etc pre-installed that this will pull quite a lot of dependencies.

Comment: Be aware that it pulls a lot of KDE stuff. On my fresh ubuntu-gnome install 'kdeconnect' wanted to pull 550mb of dependencies.

Comment: @mace: It was just a suggestion based on what the user said, and nobody else seems to have come up with a better one yet for the OP.

Comment: @paranoia: I didn't oppose your suggestion. I just pointed out that it pulls a lot of dependencies. I think people should be aware of it.

Comment: @mace: Thank you, that is a good point. I have added it to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Gnome extension : https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/